# how to make an extrinsic that allows election commission (author+validator) to upload the encoded candidate list to the blockchain

Tags: substrate-node-template, extrinsic

I am trying to make a substrate solo blockchain for the election voting using homomorphic encryption scheme use case.

Till now, I have created a permissioned blockchain, used the node authorization pallet, and authorized two election commission nodes for authoring and validating blocks and two voter nodes with the FULL node role.

referance:(https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-a-blockchain/authorize-specific-nodes/)

I have a doubt how do I create an encoded identity for each candidate for election(homomorphic encryption) and make an extrinsic that only allows election commission nodes to upload to the blockchain the candidate list with their encoded identity and manifesto before the beginning of the election in the setup phase?